# метод splice() цепочкой

Tags: javascript

`let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(3, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c');`
Почему в консоли пустой массив? Если разделить код на две строки то все в порядке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> Return value
>
> An array containing the deleted elements.

или

> Возвращаемое значение
>
> Массив с удаленными элементами.

У вас удаленных элементов - ноль.

```
...splice(3, 0, 'a', ...
             ^ - deleteCount
```

---

*Я вижу, Вы так и не прочитали документацию.*